# npm run order if directory not exist

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I have `npm` package.json script which i need to run only if the `dist` folder doesn't exist.

In my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "predev": "! test dist && webpack --config=webpack.dll.config.js
}
```

But npm tell '! test dist' is error.

How can i fix it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[ -d dist ] || webpack --config=webpack.dll.config.js

bingo (*^__^*)